# Axios responses types with different status

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

i want to do a type for axios response depened on status code:
**types**:

```
type SuccessResponseData = {
    users: ....
};

interface SuccessResponse
    extends AxiosResponse<SuccessResponseData, any> {
    status: 200;
}

type FailResponseData = {
    message: string;
};
interface FailResponse extends AxiosResponse<FailResponseData, any> {
   status: 400;
}
export type Response = SuccessResponse | FailResponse;
```

and this is how I am using it:

```
const response = await axios
  .post<SuccessResponse, AxiosResponse<SuccessResponse>>(
    endpoint,
    data,
  )
  .catch((e: AxiosError<FailResponse>) => {
    return e.response;
  });

return response as Response;
```

but the response is not compatible with Response

Answer (score 0):

Try having "SuccessResponse" as the response within a .then instead of to the post directly.

".post" can return a success or failure which then hits ".then" or ".catch"